# to_datetime Value Error: at least that [year, month, day] must be specified Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I am reading from two different CSVs each having date values in their columns. After read_csv I want to convert the data to datetime with the to_datetime method. The formats of the dates in each CSV are slightly different, and although the differences are noted and specified in the to_datetime format argument, the one converts fine, while the other returns the following value error.

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be sp
ecified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

first dte.head()

```
0  10/14/2016  10/17/2016  10/19/2016    8/9/2016  10/17/2016   7/20/2016
1   7/15/2016   7/18/2016   7/20/2016    6/7/2016   7/18/2016   4/19/2016
2   4/15/2016   4/14/2016   4/18/2016   3/15/2016   4/18/2016   1/14/2016
3   1/15/2016   1/19/2016   1/19/2016  10/19/2015   1/19/2016  10/13/2015
4  10/15/2015  10/14/2015  10/19/2015   7/23/2015  10/14/2015   7/15/2015
```

this dataframe converts fine using the following code:

```
dte = pd.to_datetime(dte, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

or

```
dte = pd.to_datetime(dte[x], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

the second dtd.head()

```
0   2004-01-02 2004-01-02  2004-01-09 2004-01-16  2004-01-23  2004-01-30
1   2004-01-05 2004-01-09  2004-01-16 2004-01-23  2004-01-30  2004-02-06
2   2004-01-06 2004-01-09  2004-01-16 2004-01-23  2004-01-30  2004-02-06
3   2004-01-07 2004-01-09  2004-01-16 2004-01-23  2004-01-30  2004-02-06
4   2004-01-08 2004-01-09  2004-01-16 2004-01-23  2004-01-30  2004-02-06
```

this csv doesn't convert using either:

```
dtd = pd.to_datetime(dtd, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

or

```
dtd = pd.to_datetime(dtd, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

It returns the value error above. Interestingly, however, using the parse_dates and infer_datetime_format as arguments of the read_csv method work fine. What is going on here?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can `stack` / `pd.to_datetime` / `unstack`

```
pd.to_datetime(dte.stack()).unstack()
```

[image]

***explanation***
`pd.to_datetime` works on a string, list, or `pd.Series`. `dte` is a `pd.DataFrame` and is why you are having issues. `dte.stack()` produces a a `pd.Series` where all rows are stacked on top of each other. However, in this stacked form, because it is a `pd.Series`, I can get a vectorized `pd.to_datetime` to work on it. the subsequent `unstack` simply reverses the initial `stack` to get the original form of `dte`

Comment: how does this work? I don't understand the logic of the operation

Comment: ahh, ok. Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: @piRSquared - I think you can add your comment to answer ;)

Answer (score 24):

For me works [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print (dtd)
            1           2           3           4           5           6
0                                                                        
0  2004-01-02  2004-01-02  2004-01-09  2004-01-16  2004-01-23  2004-01-30
1  2004-01-05  2004-01-09  2004-01-16  2004-01-23  2004-01-30  2004-02-06
2  2004-01-06  2004-01-09  2004-01-16  2004-01-23  2004-01-30  2004-02-06
3  2004-01-07  2004-01-09  2004-01-16  2004-01-23  2004-01-30  2004-02-06
4  2004-01-08  2004-01-09  2004-01-16  2004-01-23  2004-01-30  2004-02-06


dtd = dtd.apply(pd.to_datetime)

print (dtd)
           1          2          3          4          5          6
0                                                                  
0 2004-01-02 2004-01-02 2004-01-09 2004-01-16 2004-01-23 2004-01-30
1 2004-01-05 2004-01-09 2004-01-16 2004-01-23 2004-01-30 2004-02-06
2 2004-01-06 2004-01-09 2004-01-16 2004-01-23 2004-01-30 2004-02-06
3 2004-01-07 2004-01-09 2004-01-16 2004-01-23 2004-01-30 2004-02-06
4 2004-01-08 2004-01-09 2004-01-16 2004-01-23 2004-01-30 2004-02-06
```

Comment: Awesome. Very simple. Thanks!

Comment: Glad can help you!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here and didn't realize I needed to accept it. However, I'm still curious what the reason was for the error. Any ideas?

Comment: I think problem is `to_datetime` need `Series` in old versions of pandas, in newer I get error  `AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'lower'`, because it need minimal 3 column with `year`, `month` and `day` - see first example in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Comment: @Dorian821 also notice that jezrael's answer uses `apply` which takes each column of the `dtd` and uses `pd.to_datetime`.  This works because each column is a `pd.Series` and is perfect for using `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you for better explanation.

Answer (score 6):

It works for me:

```
dtd.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,errors = 'coerce', format = '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

This way you can use function attributes like above (errors and format). See more https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: The lambda function is completely unnecessary as you can pass kwargs to `apply` that will be used as arguments in the applied function eg. `dtd.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce', format=...)`

Answer (score -3):

Just would like to add - errors = 'coerce' to avoid any errors / NULL values you might have

```
dtd = dtd.apply(pd.to_datetime(errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: Generally, Errors = 'coerce' should be last choice since the error may be due to "NULL" values