# Merging Datetime column and Int column as hours replacing 00 - ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, facebook-prophet

I have a dataframe with two columns that are:

- A `datetime` column with the following format `%Y-%m-%d`
- An `int` column

They represent a day and an hour.
I want to merge because then I want to give to `prophet` so I need to convert to this format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

I tried this way:

```
example={"date":["2018-04-18","2018-04-18","2018-04-18"],"alert_h":[4,17,23]}

df=pd.DataFrame(example)

df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']) #I am converting str to datetime just for creating the example, I have already in the original df a datetime format

df.assign(date_h=pd.to_datetime(df[['date','alert_h']], format='%Y-%m-%d %h'))
```

I receive the following error message.

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

I read these following questions:

- [Value Error at least that year month day must be specified](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992411/to-datetime-value-error-at-least-that-year-month-day-must-be-specified-pand)
- [How to convert columns into one date time column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350806/how-to-convert-columns-into-one-datetime-column-in-pandas)
- [Convert Pandas Column to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763344/convert-pandas-column-to-datetime)

If this is a duplicate, feel free to close this question I will study any other link because I was not able to find a specific question to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st method:**

```
newdf=df['date'].str.split('-',expand=True).assign(hour=df['alert_h'])
newdf=newdf.astype(str)
newdf.columns=['year','month','day','hour']
df['date_h']=pd.to_datetime(newdf,format='%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s')
```

**2nd method:**

```
example={"date":["2018-04-18","2018-04-18","2018-04-18"],"alert_h":[4,17,23]}
df=pd.DataFrame(example)
date_h=df['date']+' '+df['alert_h'].astype(str)+':00:00'
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date_h']=pd.to_datetime(date_h)
```

**Edit(3rd method):**

Method by [`@MrFuppes`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10197418/mrfuppes) (It is more efficient):

```
df['date_h']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['alert_h'], unit='h')
```

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks for the suggestion...Added Your Answer :)